# calculating cost based on % on total cost

Tags: javascript, math

If you have an in app item and want to make a profit of lets say for example $0.99 and the market takes 30% what would the calculation be to find the cost you would have to charge to get $0.99 after paying the 30%. Please demonstrate in an algebraic expression to show how its calculated.

What i have so far
`price_want = 0.99`
`percent = 30%`
`total = price_want -(price_want * percent)`
so the `total price` ends up being $0.693. 
if i set `price_want` to $1.42 then total is $0.994 
I'm attempting to get a calculation that gets the `total` and `percent` on one side and the `price_want` on the other side of the equation so i can simply put in the `price_want` and get what the `total price` should be.

update to make it code related. This is what i have so far.

```
function calc(profit,percentage){
   return profit+(profit*percentage);
}
```

its getting me close to the right number but not close enough. if i pass it (0.99,0.3) I want to get 1.42 as my return amount.

Comment: `profit = total - (total * percent)`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Comment: everything about programming is mathematics. A computer is just doing math adding and subtracting bits. At no point is a computer not doing math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is plain math, not really programming, but let's do this any way: when you charge X, Y% goes to whoever, and you're left with Z. Given Z and Y, find X. Let's first make sure Y runs form 0 to 1, not 0 to 100, because that's way more useful.

```
Z = X - Y*X
-> Z = (Y + 1-Y) * X - Y*X
```

(concrete example of what just happened: X = (0.7 + 0.3)*X = 0.7*X + 0.3*X)

```
-> Z = Y*X + (1-Y)*X - Y*X
```

Obviously YX - YX cancels out, leaving us with

```
-> Z = (1-Y) * X
-> Z / (1-Y) = X
```

done. If we take Z = 0.99 (almost a buck) and Y = 0.3 (a 30% cut), we'll need to charge X = 1.4142...

But next time just search the web for the maths answer, because there's a million pages explaining how to calculate with rates and interests, geared towards as many age ranges.

Comment: Just checked your math and it's getting the correct results every time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is

```
profit / (1 - percent / 100.0)
```

Comment: i'm getting `0.99/(1-.3/100)=0.992979`

Comment: that's because you're not reading your own statement - you said percentages, so if you plug in 0.3, you're plugging in 0.3%, which is a factor 1.003... if you're thinking of values between 0 and 1, not 0 and 100, you're not dealing with percentages and you've already done the factor division.